# Hibernate config -- Teradata -- DBC.UDTInfo

Tags: java, hibernate, teradata

I am attempting to interface my java application with Teradata, but when I call org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration#buildSessionFactory, I get the following error:

ERROR: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 5315] [SQLState HY000] The user does not have SELECT access to DBC.UDTInfo.TypeName

After googling around a bit, it seems that the only solution that anyone talks about is just getting select access to DBC.UDTInfo.  But, supposing that this is not an option for me, is there another way around this problem?

(This is a crosspost from forums.hibernate.org -- still waiting for the admin to review and post it)

The full stack trace...

```
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:05 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion  
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.3.Final}  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>  
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:05 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider  
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:05 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>  
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure  
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator  
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver] at URL [jdbc:teradata://<serveraddr>]  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator  
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=****, password=****}  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator  
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:06 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>  
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:08 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>  
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.TeradataDialect  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:09 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation  
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:09 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection  
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@e22bdd] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions  
WARN: SQL Error: 5315, SQLState: HY000  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions  
ERROR: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 5315] [SQLState HY000] The user does not have SELECT access to DBC.UDTInfo.TypeName.  
Oct 26, 2016 9:57:10 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop  
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:teradata://<serveraddr>]  
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error accessing column metadata: <schemaname>.cr_test1  
. . . at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)  
. . . at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)  
. . . at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.addColumns(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:580)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.extractTableInformation(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:206)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processTableResults(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:395)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getTables(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:337)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:120)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:65)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:203)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:110)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:177)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)  
. . . at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)  
. . . at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)  
. . . at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)  
. . . at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)  
. . . at <mypackage>.StoreData.experiment00(StoreData.java:45)  
. . . at <mypackage>.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:15)  
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 5315] [SQLState HY000] The user does not have SELECT access to DBC.UDTInfo.TypeName.  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:308)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:114)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:386)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:328)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.doNonPrepExecuteQuery(TDStatement.java:316)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeQuery(TDStatement.java:1105)  
. . . at com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDatabaseMetaData.getColumns(TeraDatabaseMetaData.java:3297)  
. . . at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.addColumns(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:553)  
. . . ... 15 more
```

Comment: Well, Hibernate, should use the `UDTInfoV` view (*public*  has Select right) instead of using the base table (nobody has rights on that).

Comment: Thank you, dnoeth.  Do you know how to tell Hibernate to look at UDTInfoV instead of UDTInfo when it runs its initial configuration routine?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know about Hibernate...

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I have [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40269921/hibernate-teradata-how-to-force-hibernate-to-query-from-dbc-udtinfov-instea) a related question on how to force Hibernate to use UDTInfoV instead of UDTInfo.